# Visualise 2 data frame columns with True or False values as a Venn diagram using Python? Truth table to Venn diagram?

Tags: python, diagram

I am trying to visualise a data frame which consists of True and False values and I would like to create a Venn diagram which compare these and display based on the count of intersection of a and b is true , only a is true, only b is true, and outside would be not a or b.
[Please find the image for the corresponding Venn diagram attached.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oXDfW.png)

```
|---------------------|------------------|
|          A          |         B        |
|---------------------|------------------|
|        True         |      False       |
|---------------------|------------------|
|        True         |      False       | 
|---------------------|------------------|
|        True         |      False       |
|---------------------|------------------|
|        True         |      True        |
|---------------------|------------------|
|        False        |      False       |
|---------------------|------------------|
|        False        |      False       |
|---------------------|------------------|
|        False        |      True        |
|---------------------|------------------|
|        True         |      False       |
|---------------------|------------------|
```

Comment: Can you provide the code to reproduce your data frame?

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a special package for this [matplotlib_venn](https://pypi.org/project/matplotlib-venn/) for this.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib_venn import venn2

# Create the numbers for the diagram
# This will depend on the format of your A and B, I'm assuming numpy arrays
only_a = sum(A & ~B)
only_b = sum(B & ~A)
a_and_b = sum(A & B)

venn2(subsets = (only_a, only_b, a_and_b), set_labels = ('Group A', 'Group B'))
```